# Value of EditText in Custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have **ListActivity** , **onClick** of each item a **Custom Dialog** appears.**Custom Dialog** contains spinner and EditText Now i am not able to get the value of EditText, while debug value of EditText is coming as blank or "".

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    positionList=position;

    HashMap<String,Object>temp =(HashMap<String ,Object>)list.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) CommonScreen6.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_screen,null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(CommonScreen6.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Select Option");
    alertDialog.setView(layout);

    Spinner answerList=(Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAnswerList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAnswerType = new ArrayAdapter<String> (CommonScreen6.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,(ArrayList<String>)temp.get(Constants.answerDesc));

    adapterAnswerType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);

    answerList.setAdapter(adapterAnswerType);            
    answerList.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayList<String> answerDescList=(ArrayList<String>)temp.get(Constants.answerDesc);

    answerList.setSelection(answerDescList.indexOf(temp.get(Constants.defaultAnswerDesc)));

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Submit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
      {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
               {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) CommonScreen6.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_screen,null);
      EditText editText=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.remark);
      String remark=editText.getText().toString();

      HashMap<String,Object>temp =(HashMap<String ,Object>)list.get(positionList);
            temp.put(Constants.remark, remark);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are not getting any values is because you are reinflating the layout just before you read the values, thus resetting values to the defaults.
I suppose that you would like to findViewById on the `v` argument that was given to the onListItemClick method, instead of reinflating the layout.

That is, instead of

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) CommonScreen6.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_screen,null);
EditText editText=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.remark);
```

try something like

```
EditText editText=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.remark);
```

You might need to make the `v` variable final, in order for this to work.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Your logic very correct . But  EditText editText=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.remark); doesn't works . Any ways thanks a lot dude :)

Comment: Can please also explain me what does inflater.inflate do ?

Comment: The call of the method inflate on a LayoutInflater is described in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)
It basically turns a view as defined in your XML files into a concrete instance of this view, as a Java object.